# "Adding sign-in with Microsoft" example does not work on my working VDI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-active-directory

Good day everyone!

Background: I have old legacy ASP.NET MVC on premise application running on local windows IIS. I'm investigating ways to integrate this application with Azure AD authentication. As far as I can understand ([Windows IIS integration with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/11093/windows-iis-integration-with-azure-ad)) it's not possible to do it directly because of the Azure AD authentication can be added at the application level only. So I'm thinking integrating one of the MSAL library for adding Azure AD authentication.

Using this windows manual ([Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to a web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet)), I've downloaded sample windows application ([ASP.NET code sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/archive/master.zip)) from this learn page and tried to run it within the Visual Studio 2022 in debug mode on my azure virtual work machine (based on VDI platform).

And Azure AD authentication does not work. When I click "Sign in with windows" button on the start application page, I get [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXv7S.jpg):

> Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found.

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

> Requested URL: /login.aspx

This sample works fine on my local laptop in exactly the same state. I suggest that any security utilities might be the reason, but I don't know how to check it. I can't disable security apps on my working machine, and maybe there are any restrictions on the network level I don't even know nothing about.

**Could somebody suggest any ways to solve this problem? Or maybe still ways to find the reason of this problem?**

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Have you tested folder permissions? Or use Failed Request Tracing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing generate logs.

Comment: project folder has all possible permissions...

Comment: May you can refer to this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/264d058e-540a-4f04-b0fc-2e9a679081f5/aspnet-looking-for-loginaspx-why?forum=aspgettingstarted.

Comment: TengFeiXie, you're my life-saver and time-saver! Thank you!

Adding <authentication mode="None" /> solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

to **<system.web>** section in web.config file.

Thank a lot to [TengFeiXie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20058276/tengfeixie) for providing me with useful link.